# How to hide/display an anonymous div without affect other divs

Tags: html, show-hide, anonymous

I want to hide an anonymous-child div which has a child-div also. I want also to display the anonymous div by clicking on div#child2.

I don't have any authority to change/add/remove ids or classes.

So I did this:

```
<div id="parent">
<!-- the anonymous div which I want to hide and display by clicking on div#child-2 -->
   <div> 
      <div id="Container1" >
         <div id="Container1">  
         <object>.....</object>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div onclick="appear()" id="child-2">
      <div id="child-of-child"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#parent div:first-child {
display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function appear() {
document.getElementById("Container1").document.display="block !important";
}
</script>
```

The problem is that this type of css has affected the div#child-of-child and div#Container1 because the css reffering to every first child of any div.

So, my first question is:

How can I hide the anonymous div without having any effect to another div and display that later by clicking on div#child-2.

Second:
In this type of javascript code the styling of "block !important" works as it is?

Third:
The div#child2 doesn't have any content by itself. It includes another div which has content. If I set on div#child2 an event like `onclick="appear()";` it works?

Forth:
In case that there is no way to avoid any effect to other divs is there any way to display  the anonymous div and div#Container1?

Comment: which one do you want to toggle by clicking #child-2, and which one you don't want to toggle at the same time? i.e. which is the "another" div?

Comment: Please read http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object

Basically you should have access to the clicked object reference trough the event parameter in the handler function.

Comment: I want to display every div from anonymous div by clicking #child-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to only hide the first child within the `#parent` div:

```css
div#parent div:first-child div:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

**EDIT**

To make `Container1` appear afterwards, do the following in js (notice: I removed `!important' as I don't believe that is allowed, removing it made the code work - you can try it out below through the Fiddle link):

```
function appear() {
    document.getElementById("Container1").style.display="block";
}
```

**[FIDDLER](http://jsfiddle.net/8LvveoL3/1/)**

Comment: just added that to my answer, sorry.

Comment: One more question when whole these area (<div> <div id="Container1" >
<div id="Container1"> ) is not displayed anymore, how can I display the second div#Container1 also? Because with the given method it displays only the first div#Container1 to me.

Comment: well, for starters, you shouldn't have 2 elements with the same `id`, also, there was no content so there's nothing to display... so give it another `id`, then add a line to your js function that will make it display too.